# Record the speakers output, as in capturing streaming audio

Tags: audio, osx-lion

I want to capture the audio streaming from the speakers. Is there a freeware program that will do this in MacBook Pro with 10.7 Lion

Answer (score 0):

Use the free and open source [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/).

Set the record sound control to "Wave Outmix" or "Recording Control" in your system sound setting.

Comment: Doesn't work really. The OP is on OS X, and there's no such option.

Answer (score -1):

You need to find "Audio MIDI Setup" in Utilities. There you select what to actually record. Audacity sort of works well...

Comment: How exactly do you set up *Audio MIDI Setup* to perform what the OP wants? I'm really not sure how this would work.

Comment: By routing mixer output to recording input ?

Comment: How? Can you post a screenshot or a step by step list?

Comment: search on audacity docs - audio midi setup ....

Comment: I thought Audio MIDI Setup from OS X. Can't you please post a description?

Comment: Description: "Audio MIDI Setup"

Comment: Your answer is anything but useful. OS X's *Audio MIDI Setup.app* can't do it (at least not that I know of), and Audacity has no "Audio MIDI Setup" option, and you can only select the Built-in Microphone or Line-In as recording option. So can you please answer the question properly?

Comment: Due to DRM loby digital loopback is cut off... 
Older (core 2 age) macs could do it, G3+ had good sound boards and also could not
In theory linux or BSD driver for particular card should contain enough to write a rdiver which reroutes streams right.